# How to select a row from table1 if the row id isn't present in table2 more than x times

Tags: mysql

```
accounts as a1        | team_logs as tl1
--------------------------------------------------------
id  Name      counter | id  team_id  user_id  account_id
1   Account 1    2    | 1        1       100         1
2   Account 2    2    | 2        2       200         1
3   Account 3    0    | 3        3       300         2
...                   | 4        2       200         2
```

This is an account review app. Based on the 2 tables above a query is needed that will output 1 account from a1 table based on the tl1 records as below:

1. A team member is requesting an account, and once an account is assigned to him a log entry is made in tl1 that an account_id is assigned to him.
2. An account can be assigned to a Team only once.
3. An account can be assigned to x teams (In the above example we have only 3 teams).
4. An record can be reviewed x times(In the example above it can be reviewed 3 times).

I had a project where I had only 3 teams and each teams logs were stored in its own table, and I had this query which worked:

Example for Team1

```
SELECT `a1`.* 
FROM `accounts` AS `a1` 
    LEFT JOIN `team1_logs` AS `tl1` ON tl1.account_id = a1.id 
WHERE (tl1.account_id IS NULL) 
AND (a1.counter < '3') 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

a1 has a counter column which has a value that represents the number of times a row was shown to teams. Now my project can house x teams, we made the teams dynamic, so making a table log for each team isn't an option.

So in the above tables if i want an account to be reviewed(assigned to a team member) 3 times.

- Account 1 can be reviewed 1 more time by any team that isn't 1 and 2
- Account 2 can be reviewed 1 more time by any team that isn't 2 and 3
- What would my new query need to look like if i want to get the next first available record, based on the 1-4 criteria from above?
- The data in Table 2 is more than enough, you don't need to know any other 
  data to make the needed query.
- team_id is an query input (since we need to output an account to the team 
  member)

**Answer**

Assuming that I am a team member of team 1

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT account_id, team_id FROM team_logs) AS tl1 ON a.id = tl1.account_id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT account_id FROM team_logs WHERE team_id =1)
AND a.counter < 3
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Comment: 'counter' is being incremented when a log entry is made for the record.

Comment: so with `(a1.counter < '2')` i just said that an account can be assigned 2 times in the example.

Comment: Where is the review limit stored? (I find your use of 'x' for both assignment limits and review limits either confusing or contradictory)

Comment: The number of rows in table 2 doesn't seem relevant, since the `counter` column should be the same.

Comment: the review limit is the number 2 from my above comment, and it's stored in other part of my app. The id of the rows in table 2 is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see which teams are not allowed to review the account again, join with a subquery that uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the list of teams that have reviewed it.

```
SELECT a.*, 3 - counter AS remaining_reviews, IFNULL(tl.already_reviewed, '') AS already_reviewed
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT account_id, GROUP_CONCAT(team_id ORDER BY team_id) AS already_reviewed
    FROM team_logs
    GROUP BY account_id) AS tl ON a.id = tl.account_id
WHERE a.counter < 3
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5ACcmBNJxsUGoKpJJuWuQ/0)

Comment: Thank you vary much @Barmar i'l need this for the Stats.

Comment: It might bee that i haven't wrote precisely what i need. I wanted to get the next first available record, based on the 1-4 criteria from the question.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding the question, I thought I figured it out. Give better examples of the input and output that you want.

Comment: So we are pulling 1 account and assigning them to a team member.

Comment: The query needs to output an account_id that hasn't been reviewed 3 times. And that wasn't reviewed already by any of the users that belong to the team of the reviewing user.

Comment: Because a record can be reviewed only once by a team member from let's say Team1. And after that let's say it's locked, and can't be assigned any more to any of the team members from Team 1. So now that same record can be assigned to Team2 and 3 until one of their team members reviews it. Once a record is reviewed by all 3 Teams it's locked ( finished ), that is why i used the counter in my example although in my example i counted till 2 and not 3, maybe that was  confusing, il update the number

Comment: Can someone help me with the query i need? Tnx

Comment: Please put the clarifications in the question, not comments. Is the team ID an input into this? Is there another table listing the members of a team? Given the example data you showed, what would the output be?

Comment: I think you basically need to do two LEFT JOINs. Join with a subquery that returns all the accounts with COUNT(*) >= 3, and another that finds all the users in the same team. But I'm still not really understanding the logic, so I can't put it all together myself.

Comment: I have updated the question. Table2 has all the data needed for the query, teamId is an query input since each user can belong to 1Team. If i could reach out to you directly i would, but i don't see an option like that here.

Comment: Here's the result of your query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDwSueTntjZ9Dhi1EX9BYp/1. It returns Account 2 twice and Account 3 once. Is that correct?

Comment: it would be good if it wouldn't return Account2 twice. I tested it on my end on a large data set and haven't spotted it. Any suggestions for me how to fix this, or it's still unclear what i want?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT a.*`

Comment: Thank you, that will be perfect